# clang-formatで、アロー演算子の前後に半角空白を入れたい

Tags: c++, c

clang-formatの設定ファイル.clang-formatを編集しています。

アロー演算子の前後に半角空白を入れたいのですが、
方法がお分かりになる方お教えください。

例として、`tmp->val;` が `tmp -> val;`になる事を望んでいます。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 以下の正規表現を用いた置換をシェルスクリプトに記述しました。
正規表現に明るくないため間違いがあると思います。 
clang-format $1 | sed -E 's/([^\ ])->([^\ ])/\1 -> \2/g' | sed -E 's/([\ ])->([^\ ])/\1-> \2/g' | sed -E 's/([^\ ])->([\ ])/\1 ->\2/g' | sed -E 's/\ {0,}->\ {0,}/ -> /g' | sed -E 's/->\ {1,}->/-> ->/g'

Comment: clang-format さん、一旦はそれで解決なさったということでしたら、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)なさって頂いても大丈夫です (推奨されています)。私も詳しくないなりに少し調べてみましたが、["Clang-Format Style Options"](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#adding-additional-style-options) の中に書かれているように clang-format は設定ファイル上で新しいオプションを作ることは考えていないのかもしれません。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
私はvimのプラグインのvim-clang-formatを使おうとしていて、
vim-clang-formatが内部でclang-formatを呼び出しているため、
clang-formatの処理の後に置換処理を挟めないか試しています。
今のところうまくいっていないのですがこの質問ではアドバイス通り自己解決とさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上のコメントで一旦自己解決した為改めて書かせていただきます
clang-formatでの直接的な解決を諦め、
sedによる置換処理を行うことにしました。

```
sed -e 's/\s*->\s*/\ ->\ /ge' -e 's/->\s\+->/-> ->/ge'
```